# Get all variations of a string using Levenshtein distance

Tags: c#, algorithm, levenshtein-distance

I found a lot of implementation doing the calculation of Levenshtein between 2 strings, but is there any implementation that can generate all variations using Levenshtein distance (max 2) for one given string.

The reason is, I'm using ElasticSearch to execute some fuzzy search, but with the load of queries that I have I have some performance issue because ELK will calculate those possibilities each time, I want to store those values once.

Comment: Do you intend to produce strings by inserting a wild-card character like `?`, or all characters? Because the later would produce a huge number of strings.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *"can generate all variations [...] for one given string"*? Generate all strings with a maximium distance of 2 for a given string? That will be a huge amount of data. Consider "word", just replacing a single character gives you 100 new words, adding a single character gives you 130 new words, replacing 2 characters gives you about 3700 new words, replacing one and adding one gives you ?? new words, ... all within the Levenshtein distance of 2 ...

Comment: Yes, Like mention by @derpirscher, I want to "Generate all strings with a maximium distance of 2 for a given string" ; I know it's a lot of possibilities but this is how the fuzzy works in ElasticSeach, butr instead of asking ELK to do fuzzy, I want to pre-compute all possibilities before, and ask ELK to do a simple comparaison with all pre-computed possibilities.

Comment: You mean you want to send millions (if you filter them somehow early on further to not excess memory limits)  of search terms to Elsasticsearch instead of using the build in function of Elasticsearch? To gain what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most commonly cited reference implementation for generating an edit distance is in Python, you can see it [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39858843).

The original author linked subsequent implementations in other languages at the bottom of his blog under the heading [*Other Computer Languages*](https://norvig.com/spell-correct.html). There are 4 implementations in C#, [this one in particular](https://frederictorres.blogspot.com/2011/04/how-to-write-spelling-corrector-from.html) is functional (I'm unsure under what license those implementations are published, so I won't transcribe them into this thread).

But using wildcard searches with ElasticSearch is the correct approach. The engine will implement [approximate string matching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximate_string_matching) as efficiently as possible - there are a number of different algorithms this can be based on and the optimal choice depends on your data structure, etc.

You can simplify the use by generating the edit distance yourself, but in most cases if you're using a database or engine their implementation will have better performance. (This is a computationally expensive task, there's no way around that.)